# Write nested SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 tables

**Table1**

```
ID    Name
--------------------
 1    John Carter
 2    Jack Hammer
 3    John Adams
 4    John Doe
 5    Brian Adams
```

**Table2**

```
ID     ID_FromTable1
-----------------------------
 1        2
 2        3
 3        1
 4        1
 5        1
 6        2
 7        3
 8        1
 9        1
10        5
11        4
12        5
13        4
```

`ID` in both tables is the primary key

- `ID_FromTable1` is the foreign key pointing to `ID` of `Table1`.

Now I do something like this:

```
SELECT ID 
FROM Table1 
WHERE Name like '%John%'
```

This will give me the `ID`s `1`, `3`, `4`.

Now using these `ID`s, I want to write a query on `Table2` to delete all entries where `ID_FromTable1` are `1`, `3`, `4`.

Please help me write one single SQL query to get all the `ID`s from `Table1` where Name is `'John'` and then using those `ID`s to delete entries from `Table2`.

I hope I have made the question clear. Do let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, ***PLEASE*** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! No need for all those messy `&nbsp;` and `<br>` tags, in that case!!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for the info. I will keep in mind from next time.

Comment: @notulysses I am using SQL Server 2008R2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `IN` with subquery:

```
DELETE FROM Table2 
WHERE ID_FromTable1 IN ( SELECT ID 
                         FROM Table1 
                         WHERE Name LIKE '%John%' )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. This worked for me. I was getting stuck in the syntax and was constantly getting some errors.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you can do it with this join

```
delete table2
from table2
join table1 on table2.id_fromtable1 = table1.id
WHERE t1.Name like '%John%'
```

Comment: That's non-standard SQL. You should add the DBMS on which this will work (the question is not tagged with a specific DBMS)